# How install saltslack in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu

Hi i have problem to install saltslack in ubuntu 19.10

I try install from this document
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html
and can't install 
perhaps for ver ubuntu
please help

```
sudo sh bootstrap_salt.sh
```

```
 *  INFO: Running version: 2020.01.29
 *  INFO: Executed by: sh
 *  INFO: Command line: 'bootstrap_salt.sh '

 *  INFO: System Information:
 *  INFO:   CPU:          GenuineIntel
 *  INFO:   CPU Arch:     x86_64
 *  INFO:   OS Name:      Linux
 *  INFO:   OS Version:   5.3.0-29-generic
 *  INFO:   Distribution: Ubuntu 19.10

 *  INFO: Installing minion
 *  INFO: Found function install_ubuntu_stable_deps
 *  INFO: Found function config_salt
 *  INFO: Found function preseed_master
 *  INFO: Found function install_ubuntu_stable
 *  INFO: Found function install_ubuntu_stable_post
 *  INFO: Found function install_ubuntu_restart_daemons
 *  INFO: Found function daemons_running
 *  INFO: Found function install_ubuntu_check_services
 *  INFO: Running install_ubuntu_stable_deps()
Hit:1  eoan InRelease
Get:2  eoan-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:3  eoan-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Get:4  eoan-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:5  xenial InRelease [11.5 kB]
Ign:6 /saltstack/salt/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Get:7 /ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 Packages [197 kB]
Get:8  xenial/partner amd64 Packages [3,120 B]
Get:9  xenial/partner Translation-en [1,672 B]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/saltstack/salt/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:11 apt/ubuntu/ubuntu14/latest trusty InRelease
Hit:12 apt/ubuntu/18.04/amd64/latest bionic InRelease
Err:13 apt/ubuntu/ubuntu14/latest trusty Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.226.145.74 80]
Get:14 ubuntu eoan-updates/universe amd64 Packages [92.0 kB]
Reading package lists...
 * ERROR: Failed to run install_ubuntu_stable_deps()!!!
```

Answer (score -1):

Under Ubuntu, you should install from the package manager so

```
apt install salt-master
```

for the master node and

```
apt install salt-minion
```

for the minions. Alternatively, you may add the "git" tag to the boostrap shell script to get the latest version cloned from git.